# Can a pointer be converted into void pointer?

Tags: c

Can a pointer be converted into void pointer?

Comment: Ask a better question or this is likely to be closed.

Comment: What, it's too obvious for you? Some people aren't at the level you're at.

Answer (score 5):

Any non-qualified (not `const`, `volatile`, etc.) data pointer implicitly converts to `void *`, and `void *` implicitly converts to any data pointer. Function pointers do not implicitly convert, and are not guaranteed to be representable as `void *`.

Comment: @ephemient: Yes, POSIX explicitly requires a flat memory model that's at least 32 bits where code and data share a common address space. One of the many ways POSIX sanitizes what C leaves implementation-defined. :-)